# JavaDB: Is it possible to change auto-increment offset on existing table?

Tags: auto-increment, javadb

Is it possible to change the auto-increment offset on a pre-existing table with JavaDB?

I'm having a problem where inserting new records usually (but not always) fails with an error complaining about using an existing key (my auto-increment column).  To populate this database, I took a dump from another database (MySQL) and used a JavaDB stored procedure to insert them all into the corresponding JavaDB table.  My theory is that inserting these records copied the existing IDs from the MySQL table.  Now the auto-increment functionality is dishing out existing IDs.  I figure explicitly setting the offset to some high number will allow the auto-increment to work again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to directly change the offset, but I managed to fix this by:

1. Changing the increment amount by X (1 million in my case).
2. Inserting a dummy record.
3. Reducing the increment amount back down to 1.
4. Deleting the dummy record.

I used this SQL statement to change the increment amount:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ALTER COLUMN col SET INCREMENT BY x
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if it's not a direct answer to the question:
With MySQL, you can do a

```
ALTER TABLE my_little_table AUTO_INCREMENT =2000
```

to set the auto increment value.